# How to iterate over 2D list to find user specified element, then delete all rows that do not contain stated element

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a 2D list to find an element that matches the user input. When a match is found, all rows of the list that do not contain that element will be removed from the list. The idea is that I can keep applying filters until i am left with what the user wants to see but I am coming unstuck at the first hurdle.

```
def catlistfun():
  for cat in appdata:
      if cat[1] not in catlist:
          catlist.append(cat[1])
```

Above is a part of my program that I have used to access the list successfully. When I try the program below it runs but no rows appear to delete.

```
def categorymenu():
  print(catlist)
  catchoice = input('Enter Chosen Category: ')
  for cats in appdata:
      if catchoice != cats[1]:
          del cats
```

I understand the way I am trying to achieve this may be quite basic but i am fairly new to python and would like to stick to something close to this if possible. Thanks

Edit: Example

```
appdata = [a,b,c,d,e,f],[a,t,e,g,h,y],[r,y,i,a,d,c]
catchoice = t
for cat in appdata:
    if catchoice != cat[1]:
        del cat
print(appdata)

output: [a,t,e,g,h,y]
```

The above is the output I am looking for but at the moment the output is

```
output: [a,b,c,d,e,f],[a,t,e,g,h,y],[r,y,i,a,d,c]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for this:

```py
[row for row in appdata if catchoice in row]
```

Please provide example input and example output to eliminate ambiguity in interpretation.

Comment: So an example of input would be hardware. If hardware is a match with any of the elements in cat[2] which is a column of categories, those rows would stay in the list while the rest are deleted/ removed. Sorry I can't attach the output as it is a large data set but when I print the list to confirm the function has worked there is no change to the list.

Comment: This is an explanation, not an example. An example is something like: `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'x', 'y'], ['z', 'x', 'c']]` and `'a'` should get `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'x', 'y']]`. Add examples to your question